# android - handle dialogFragment buttons clicks

Tags: android, fragment, android-dialogfragment

I have Activity in my app with few fragments in it. One of these fragments has a DialogFragment, it called by button click. DialogFragment has 3 buttons - positive, negative and neutral.

```
public class CompanyNotConnectedToSRDialog extends DialogFragment {

    public static final String TAG = CompanyNotConnectedToSRDialog.class.getSimpleName();

    private NotConnectedDialogListener mNotConnectedDialogListener;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.DefaultAlertDialogTheme)
                .setTitle("Register")
                .setMessage("Do you really want to register?")
                .setNeutralButton("Skip", (dialog1, which) -> {
                    mNotConnectedDialogListener.onSkipBtnNotConnectedDialogPressed();
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                .setPositiveButton("Register", (dialog12, which) -> {
                    mNotConnectedDialogListener.onSendBtnNotConnectedDialogPressed();
                })
                .create();
    }


    public interface NotConnectedDialogListener {
        void onSkipBtnNotConnectedDialogPressed();
        void onSendBtnNotConnectedDialogPressed();
    }

    public void setListener(NotConnectedDialogListener listener) {
        this.mNotConnectedDialogListener = listener;
    }
```

As you can see I created public interface that contains two methods for my skip and register buttons (cancel button listener is null so it doesn't matter) and the Setter for this listener. 
Then I implemented this interface in my fragment that calls this dialogFragment, I Overrided methods and called dialogFragment like this:

```
if (mNotConnectedDialog == null) {
            mNotConnectedDialog = new CompanyNotConnectedToSRDialog();
            mNotConnectedDialog.setListener(this);
            mNotConnectedDialog.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), CompanyNotConnectedToSRDialog.TAG);
        } else {
            mNotConnectedDialog.show(mActivity.getFragmentManager(), CompanyNotConnectedToSRDialog.TAG);
            mNotConnectedDialog.setListener(this);
        }
```

The problem is I get NullPointerException if I press the button in my parent Fragment to show DialogFragment, rotate screen and press any button in my DialogFragment, because my listener is null.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.myapp.ui.object.create.dialogs.CompanyNotConnectedToSRDialog$NotConnectedDialogListener.onSendBtnNotConnectedDialogPressed()' on a null object reference

at com.myapp.ui.object.create.dialogs.CompanyNotConnectedToSRDialog.lambda$onCreateDialog$1(CompanyNotConnectedToSRDialog.java:31)
```

How to handle these clicks and set listeners if this solution is wrong?

**PS:** please don't tell me about `android:configChanges`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the current solution doesn't work because when you rotate the dialog fragment is destroyed and recreated. So setListener isn't called. The solution depends on if your listener is an activity or another fragment.

If it's an activity you can override onAttach in your DialogFragment and set the listener there. If your listener is a fragment then in your OnCreateDialog method you can look the fragment up by the tag and set the listener that way. For example.

```
Fragment listenerFragment = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(getString(R.string.your_listener_fragment_tag));

if( listenerFragment instanceOf NotConnectedDialogListener ) {
    listener = (NotConnectedDialogListener) listenerFragment;
} else {
    //Handle what to do if you don't have a listener here. Maybe dismiss the dialog. 
}
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. I did the same and added in the "else" statement the ClassCastException, my app crashed with the.. ClassCastException. Because listenerFragment = null

Comment: Well, I used getFragmentManager and not getSupportFragmentManager because I don't have it somehow..

Comment: Yea that depends if you are using the support libraries or not. If you're not then getFragmentManager is fine. I had one type in my example the assignment should have used listenerFragment and not fragment. I've updated that. You shouldn't really get a cast exception since the if should prevent that. Could you share what you did and the line the exception occured on?

Comment: Nevermind, I used the support libraries and now it works. Thanks you. But I still have a question - is this solution a good solution? Or is it "the last breath" solution? :)

Comment: In terms of fragments I consider it a good solution. There's nothing wrong with using the fragment manager to find fragments that's what it's there. It's unfortunately not quite as elegant as using Activities and the onAttach method. But I like you have lots of places in my code where I need to use fragments and can't use activities and this is the route I take.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, after orientation change your listener is null. It's easiest to do the callback to the activity:

```
public static class DialogFragmentA extends DialogFragment {

    // Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface NotConnectedDialogListener {
        public void onX();
    }

    NotConnectedDialogListener mListener;
    ...
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (NotConnectedDialogListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement NotConnectedDialogListener");
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Now you can call mListener.onX etc. in your dialog anywhere, also after orientation change. Your container Activity must implement the interface and will receive the method call.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks

Comment: No, I can't use Activity as listener, because my Fragment has a presenter and I need to call it's methods when I click buttons in DialogFragment.

Comment: You should. You will have to redirect from the activity to the given fragment/presenter. Or use an EventBus.

Comment: So there's no way to use Fragment as listener?

Comment: Not directly, no (welcome to the complex world of fragments)

Comment: Actually you can use a fragment, I've included an example in my answer below.

Comment: Interesting. your solution is strictly 1 on 1, but there are ways around that too if you give the tag as a parameter on dialog construction. I wonder if there are drawbacks, but it seems okay to me.

Comment: The two drawbacks would be that unless your listener fragment is a retained fragment you have to be mindful of the back stack in the unlikely event your listener is created second. But it's hard for me to envision a workflow where you would do that. The other is like you said it's now a strictly one to one setup. But the way around that would be to save the tag to the instanceState and then retrieve it from there when it's recreated.

Comment: and if the base fragment is in a viewpager, you might not be able to set a tag (the viewpager sets a tag, which might change on orientation change)? just guessing...